# acknowledge order report amazon mws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am using "GetReportList" api with report list type as "_GET_ORDERS_DATA" to pull order reports from amazon. But I want to pull only new orders. How can I use the "acknowledged" field to make sure that I pull only new orders(which were not previously pulled).I observed that the "acknowledged" field is true by default. Please let me know if there is a way to pull new orders only(I am trying to avoid using timestamp here)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to acknowledge the order report when you picked it up, then you will only get order reports set to acknowledged false on the next call.

So you need to run this operation:

```
        $request1 = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_UpdateReportAcknowledgementsRequest();
        $request1->setMerchant(MERCHANT_ID);

        $idList1 = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_IdList();
        $request1->setReportIdList($idList1->withId(/* SET THE REPORT ID YOU HAVE TAKEN */));
        $request1->setAcknowledged(true);

        invokeUpdateReportAcknowledgements($service, $request1);
function invokeUpdateReportAcknowledgements(MarketplaceWebService_Interface $service, $request1)
{
    try {
        $response = $service->updateReportAcknowledgements($request1);


    } catch (MarketplaceWebService_Exception $ex) {
    var_dump($ex);
```

After you have picked up the order report, and then, you can simply request the next order report with this line:

```
 $request->setAcknowledged(false);
```

Like this, only reports you haven't set to acknowledged with the first call will be shown in the list.

The first call is described in the php API, I think it's called something like SetAcknowledgmentSample, and the second call needs to be called in the getReportListSample file

Comment: After we have picked up a report, we should set Acknowledged for the order to be true. But why set Acknowledged false before we request the new report? The Acknowledged of new report should be false by default, right?

Comment: I'm setting a **request** parameter to request all not acknowledged reports. Sure it is false by default. @YingStyle

Answer (score -1):

I think you can set them as below which I found from sample code found in Amazon Report's API sample

```
$parameters = array (
   'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
   'AvailableToDate' => new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC')),
   'AvailableFromDate' => new DateTime('-6 months', new DateTimeZone('UTC')),
   'Acknowledged' => false, 
 );

 $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportListRequest($parameters);

 $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportListRequest();
 $request->setMerchant(MERCHANT_ID);
 $request->setAvailableToDate(new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC')));
 $request->setAvailableFromDate(new DateTime('-3 months', new DateTimeZone('UTC')));
 $request->setAcknowledged(false);
```